# Special character and accent marks in Django

Tags: django, database, special-characters

I have created a search functionality in django. But there is a problem with some special characters. For example, when I searched for the chateau, it didn't show interest with the name château or when I searched for arpege, it didn't show interest with the name Arpège.

Here is my code:

```
    interest = Interest.objects.filter(
        Q(name__icontains=searched) |
        Q(text__icontains=searched) |
        Q(info1__icontains=searched) |
        Q(info2__icontains=searched) |
        Q(info4__icontains=searched) |
        Q(info5__icontains=searched) |
        Q(filter_tags__icontains=searched) |
        Q(meta_description__icontains=searched) |
        Q(meta_keywords__icontains=searched)
    ).order_by("-rating")
```

I want to be able to convert all of the special characters in the field "name" in the database first before comparing it with "searched", so I can get the Interest with the name arpège even if I typed arpege or château when I typed chateau.